# How do I find the length of header and trailer for this IT homework?

Tags: ethernet, payload

I really do not understand this question at all for my IT course. I have a homework assignment and here is the question:

An Ethernet frame contains 900 bytes of payload data.  You will need to look up the length of the header and trailer. Calculate the percentage of the frame that is overhead (do not include the preamble in the frame).

So really what is the length of the head and trailer? I cannot find info on this stuff at all!

How do you calculate percentage of frame that is overhead?

Here is another question I do not understand.

Assume an Ethernet frame is to carry 30 bytes of payload data.  What is the size of the frame in bytes?  You will need to look up the length of the header and trailer. (do not include the preamble in the frame, but do include padding if necessary)

How is frame size determined?

Comment: What part don't you understand? And this sounds like a question for your teacher.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming. In addition, questions related to understanding your homework assignment should be directed to the teacher who gave you that assignment.

Comment: ummm Google Ethernet Frame Size.....